# How to use VeeValidate or any third party package locally inside vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-tables-2, vee-validate

Ok here is the situation, I am working on a SPA with `Vue.js`. I am using `VeeValidate` in one of my component say in `Component1.vue` like this,

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';

Vue.use(VeeValidate);

export default {
    //...
}
```

In another component say in `Component2.vue` I am using `vuetable-2` which I registered like this,

```
import Vuetable from 'vuetable-2/src/components/Vuetable';

export default {
    components: {
        Vuetable
    },

   //...
}
```

The problem is that both `VeeValidate` and `Vuetable` internally depends on a computed property with same name. And as I am registering `VeeValidate` globally like `Vue.use(VeeValidate);`, if I navigate from `Component1` to `Component2`, `Vuetable` gives an error saying,

> The computed property "fields" is already defined as a prop

because `VeeValidate` already registered itself globally when I landed on `Component1`.

If I navigate to `Component2` from any other component which does not have any dependency with `VeeValidate` then it works just fine.

So here is my question,

**How do I register `VeeValidate` or any other package inside `Component1.vue` locally so that it does not influence other components?** much like registering other components inside `components: {}` object.

Answer (score 1):

Vee validate allows you to change the field and error bag names through the configuration. It's in the [docs here](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/configuration.html#configuration).

```
const config = { 
     errorBagName: 'errors', // change if property conflicts 
     fieldsBagName: 'fields',
}
```

Also maybe if interest, the [advanced configuration](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/advanced.html#inject) section explains how to inject instances into components instead of globally.

Comment: Yes I am looking for Injecting locally inside  a component, Ok let me check if it works